# How to serialize objects and properties in a particular order using FlexJson

Tags: java, flexjson

I am new to FlexJson and am trying to have some understanding in it. I started with a simple piece of code. Here is the code:

```
public class Statements {

private String parent;
private ArrayList<String> children = new ArrayList<String>();

public Statements(String parent)
{
    this.parent =parent;
}

public void setPrent(String parent)
{
    this.parent = parent;
}

public String getPrent()
{
    return parent;
}

public void setChildren(ArrayList<String> children)
{
    this.children = children;
}

public ArrayList<String> getChildren()
{
    return children;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String parent = "A";
    ArrayList<String> children = new ArrayList<String>();
    children.add("a1");
    children.add("a2");
    children.add("a3");

    Statements s = new Statements(parent);
    s.setChildren(children);
    JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer().prettyPrint(true);  
    System.out.println(serializer.exclude("*.class").include("children").serialize( s ));
}
```

}

Here is the output:

```
{
"children": [
    "a1",
    "a2",
    "a3"
],
"parent": "A"
}
```

What I was thinking to get is the following output:

```
{
"parent": "A",
"children": [
    "a1",
    "a2",
    "a3"
]
}
```

The real output is ordered alphabetically. What I am trying get is the output as show above. Could anyone please help to do this. Your assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Pretty sure the keys in a map can be any order they want... Possible duplicate of: [FlexJSON Orders Alphabetically by Default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013123)

Comment: Why do you care what order the fields come back in? If all the same data is present, then your data is semantically equivalent, and the order of variables doesn't matter.

Comment: I am working on D3 Javascript library for visualisation. It reads JSON files in a particular format. This is the format I need in order to get things visualised. This issue is blocking my way. It would be very much appreciated if you provide me with any idea to get it solved. Many thanks.